# Finding the nullity and nullspace in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I was trying to get the nullity and kernel of a matrix over the complex field in Maxima.
I get strange results, though.

I can define a matrix A:

```
M : matrix([0, 1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, -1, 0]);
A : M + %i * ident(4);
```

... for reference, it looks like this:

```
%i  1  1  0
-1 %i  0  1
 0  0 %i  1
 0  0 -1 %i
```

If I then compute the nullity with `nullity(A)`, I get 3.
If I compute the rank with `rank(A)`, I also get 3.
And if I compute the nullspace with `nullspace(A)`, I get:

```
span([-1, %i, 0, 0], [-%i, -1, 0, 0], [2%i, 2, 0, 0])
```

But this is pretty weird, because `-%i * second(...)` is `[-1, %i, 0, 0]`, which is the first vector.

And indeed, when I do `NullSpace[{{i, 1, 1, 0}, {-1, i, 0, 1}, {0, 0, i, 1}, {0, 0, -1, i}}]` in [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NullSpace[%7B%7Bi,%201,%201,%200%7D,%20%7B-1,%20i,%200,%201%7D,%20%7B0,%200,%20i,%201%7D,%20%7B0,%200,%20-1,%20i%7D%7D]), I get that the nullspace has basis `[%i, 1, 0, 0]` and is 1-dimensional (not 3-dimensional).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing everything right, as far as I can tell. The problem is a bug in Maxima, which I have reported: https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/3158/

I don't see any simple way to work around it. I am working on fixing the bug.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I really appreciate it. Will follow the bug closely.

Comment: @JonathanChan this bug is now fixed by commit c9375b3 which should be contained in the next Maxima release (5.39, which should occur soon). Sorry for the delay, thanks for the bug report, and I hope this helps.